# How to make different slogan for each content type?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have several content types, I want the slogan that shows up on the page to be different for each slogan. Is this possible?

Comment: What is the slogan? Do you mean the slogan you can configured in `admin/config/system/site-information`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a preprocess function:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['node'])){
    switch ($variables['node']->type) {
      case 'my_content_type2':
        $slogan = "my super slogan 1";
        break;
      case 'my_content_type2':
        $slogan = "my super slogan 2";
        break;
      default:
        $slogan = "my super slogan 3";
    }
    $variables['site_slogan'] = $slogan;
  }
}
```

In this case, you [preprocess the page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x) before it is sended to the template engine.
More exactly, you change the 'site_slogan' variable according to the node type.

You can add this function in a module: in this case replace "mymodule" in the function's name by the name of your module

or you can add this function in the "template.php" file of your theme folder: in this case replace "mymodule" in the function's name by the name of your theme.

Comment: I think it is good answer but it will have undefined error for some other pages. You should add `isset($variables['node'])`

Comment: You are right, I have corrected according to your comment.

Comment: Great. It works.